# How can I concatenate JS files while isolating errors to each file?

Tags: javascript, browser

## Problem

I am loading scripts from various 3rd-party developers at runtime (this app is not hosted by me, so I have lost control over the code once it's running), let's say a.js, b.js, c.js.

I want to reduce HTTP requests, so I serve them as one big concatenated file abc.js

I'd like to avoid having errors in any one file affect the execution of any of the other files. How can I achieve this?

## Non-starters

- try-catch

  Try-catch won't help with Syntax Errors. Syntax errors will cause the whole file to fail.
  It also causes issues with FunctionDeclarations which are removed from the global scope in Firefox.
- Un-concatenating

  I need to reduce requests. The files must be concatenated when they travel down the wire.

## Preferences

Maintain synchronous loading of scripts.

## Possible solutions

- Load a concatenated file as text, then evaluate each script separately. One technique for this is used by GMail Mobile - http://googlecode.blogspot.com.au/2009/09/gmail-for-mobile-html5-series-reducing.html

Any pre-existing / pre-packaged libraries that accomplish this are the best solution for me.

EDIT: My "app" is installed on-site, and is pluggable at runtime with arbitrary JS from third parties. So I never get to test all the JS together outside of production.

Comment: Have you tried [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) and block commenting?

Comment: "block commenting"? JSLint would remove syntax errors which is good.

Comment: I am not sure how this question lacks research effort or is unclear or not useful. Please comment if you downvote and I'll clarify it.

Comment: Yes, you can block comment out large sections of your script and see what errors get eliminated, if any.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. If it's one big concatenated file, the syntax error is in the one big file. If you don't concatenate the file, you get multiple requests for the separate files but at least you can pinpoint the error to the specific file. There is no way around this.

That said, unless the file is minified, any decent browser, e.g., Chrome, Safari, Firefox should show you where the error is in the developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that (unless what you suggested by loading as a text file and then evaluating them, but honestly, that's just horrendous).

What you should probably do is keep the files separated in development and once they're tested you can concatenate them in a production environment.

Comment: Didn't say it wasn't horrendous. :) Concatenating in prod-only is fine, but I don't have a dev environment that includes all production code (see my EDIT).

Answer (score 0):

Pay more money for a better server / connection or host your app on S3; whatever you're doing, the costs are probably cheaper than your time.

Comment: See my new edits. This is unfortunately not relevant to my situation.